# enforce spring boot configuration to use hibernate/mysql instead of orientdb

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm using a maven module using spring boot that has both hibernate/mysql to persist some data. In another module (which should be in the dependency list of the first module), we use orientdb as a persistence db.

When I remove the second module, the first module uses hibernate and everything works well. Though, when I add the second module to the first module's dependencies, spring boot attempts to use orientdb for persistence which is not the expected action, we want it to use hibernate.

How can I enforce spring boot to use hibernate instead?

Application.java

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableAutoConfiguration
> @ComponentScan
> public class Application {
>
>     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
>     { 
>         SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
>         CrawlerFactory.main(null);
>      } 
>
> }
> ```

```
Configuration.java
@Configuration 
@EnableTransactionManagement 
public class DatabaseConfig { 


  // ============== 
  // PRIVATE FIELDS 
  // ============== 

  @Autowired 
  private Environment _env;


  @Autowired 
  private DataSource _dataSource;


  @Autowired 
  private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean _entityManagerFactory;


  // ============== 
  // PUBLIC METHODS 
  // ============== 


  /** 
   * DataSource definition for database connection. Settings are read from 
   * the application.properties file (using the _env object). 
   */ 
  @Bean 
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(_env.getProperty("spring.datasource.driver-class-name"));
    dataSource.setUrl(_env.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    dataSource.setUsername(_env.getProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(_env.getProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
    return dataSource;
  } 


  /** 
   * Declare the JPA entity manager factory. 
   */ 
  @Bean 
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() { 
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory =
        new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); 

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(_dataSource);

    // Classpath scanning of @Component, @Service, etc annotated class 
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan(
        _env.getProperty("entitymanager.packagesToScan"));

    // Vendor adapter 
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    // Hibernate properties 
    Properties additionalProperties = new Properties();
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.dialect",  
        _env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.show_sql",  
        _env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
    additionalProperties.put(
        "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",  
        _env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties);

    return entityManagerFactory;
  } 


  /** 
   * Declare the transaction manager. 
   */ 
  @Bean 
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() { 
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = 
        new JpaTransactionManager(); 
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(
        _entityManagerFactory.getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  } 

  /** 
   * PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor is a bean post processor 
   * which adds an advisor to any bean annotated with Repository so that any 
   * platform-specific exceptions are caught and then rethrown as one 
   * Spring's unchecked data access exceptions (i.e. a subclass of  
   * DataAccessException). 
   */ 
  @Bean 
  public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() { 
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(); 
  } 
}
```

application.properties

```
# Database
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spices_crawler
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=1458
# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
entitymanager.packagesToScan=com.mta.spicegraph.builder
```

Comment: So the two modules share a package (bad idea)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find it usefull

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-two-datasources.

It shows how to define multiple datasources & assign one of them as primary.

Here is a rather full example, also contains distributes transactions - if you need it.

http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/

What you need is to create 2 configuration classes, separate the model/repository packages etc to make the config easy.

Also, in above example, it creates the data sources manually. You can avoid this using the method on spring doc, with @ConfigurationProperties annotation. Here is an example of this:

http://xantorohara.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/spring-boot-jdbc-with-multiple.html

Hope these helps.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

this is the right way to  build hibernate properties

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post and show the actual content as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.